# MInipage not working with text and array/table with theorem environment

Tags: environments, theorems, minipage

I am having a problem putting text and array side by side using minipage. I realized that the error is 
due to theorem environment, since without this it works. This is what I am getting
[image]

The code is below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm, amsmath, amssymb, mathtools, thmtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem]{theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.55\textwidth}
Group of Integers modulo $n$ consists of the set \[\{0, 1, 2, \dots, n - 1\}\] with the 
operation of addition modulo $n.$ Imagine the numbers 0 through $n - 1$ to be points on the unit circle, each 
one separated from the next by an arc of length $2\pi / n.$ To add two numbers $h$ and $k,$ start with $h$ 
and move clockwise through an arc of $k$ times $2\pi / n.$ The sum $h + k$ will be one of the numbers 0 
through $n - 1.$ From geometrical considerations it is clear that this kind of addition is associative. Zero 
is the identity element of this group and $n - h $ is the inverse of $h$ [for $h + (n - h) = n,$ which 
coincides with 0]. This group, the group of integers modulo $n,$ is represented by the symbol $Z_n.$
\end{minipage}
\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{c|cccccc} 
 +_{6} & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline 
 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\  
 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 0 \\  
 2 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 0 & 1 \\  
 3 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\  
 4 & 4 & 5 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\  
 5 & 5 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4   
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
\end{minipage}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Here is a strange one: try adding `\item` before the first minipage

Comment: @daleif Hahaaa worked like a charm. Thank you

Comment: A theorem is actually a list of one item, where the `\item` has already been called. Who says we cannot have more that one item. It comes with a cost though. LaTeX is allowed to page break at this new item

Comment: @daleif Can you write it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since theorems are implemented using lists, where the `\item` is hidden in the header we can cheat.

Try adding another `\item` before the first minipage.

Caveat larex is now allowed to page break between the theorem header and the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you prefer something like this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm, amsmath, amssymb, mathtools, thmtools,array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem]{theorem}
\begin{document}

\vspace{\topsep}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.55\textwidth}
\begin{theorem}
Group of Integers modulo $n$ consists of the set \[\{0, 1, 2, \dots, n - 1\}\] with the 
operation of addition modulo $n$. Imagine the numbers 0 through $n - 1$ to be points on 
the unit circle, each one separated from the next by an arc of length $2\pi / n$. To add 
two numbers $h$ and $k$, start with $h$ and move clockwise through an arc of $k$ times 
$2\pi / n$. The sum $h + k$ will be one of the numbers $0$ through $n - 1$. From 
geometrical considerations it is clear that this kind of addition is associative. Zero 
is the identity element of this group and $n - h $ is the inverse of $h$ [for 
$h + (n - h) = n$, which coincides with $0$]. This group, the group of integers modulo 
$n$, is represented by the symbol $Z_n$.
\end{theorem}
\end{minipage}
\hspace*{\fill}%
\raisebox{-1.2ex}{$
\begin{array}[t]{c|cccccc} 
 +_{6} & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline 
 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\  
 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 0 \\  
 2 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 0 & 1 \\  
 3 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\  
 4 & 4 & 5 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\  
 5 & 5 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4   
\end{array}
$}\par\vspace{\topsep}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you prefer center alignment:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm, amsmath, amssymb, mathtools, thmtools,array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem]{theorem}
\begin{document}

\vspace{\topsep}
\begin{minipage}{0.55\textwidth}
\begin{theorem}
Group of Integers modulo $n$ consists of the set \[\{0, 1, 2, \dots, n - 1\}\] with the 
operation of addition modulo $n$. Imagine the numbers 0 through $n - 1$ to be points on 
the unit circle, each one separated from the next by an arc of length $2\pi / n$. To add 
two numbers $h$ and $k$, start with $h$ and move clockwise through an arc of $k$ times 
$2\pi / n$. The sum $h + k$ will be one of the numbers $0$ through $n - 1$. From 
geometrical considerations it is clear that this kind of addition is associative. Zero 
is the identity element of this group and $n - h $ is the inverse of $h$ [for 
$h + (n - h) = n$, which coincides with $0$]. This group, the group of integers modulo 
$n$, is represented by the symbol $Z_n$.
\end{theorem}
\end{minipage}
\hspace*{\fill}%
$\begin{array}{c|cccccc} 
 +_{6} & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline 
 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\  
 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 0 \\  
 2 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 0 & 1 \\  
 3 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\  
 4 & 4 & 5 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\  
 5 & 5 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4   
\end{array}
$\par\vspace{\topsep}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Punctuation after in inline formulas should go outside the formula: `$Z_n$.` instead of `$Z_n.$`

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I would prefer the theorem to end after minipage as it has qedsymbol at the end. Also for the Punctuation, sometimes '.' gets to the new line if I put it outside.

Comment: @Kumarm Sorry, but there's no trace at all of QED in your question. About punctuation, TeX will *never* detach it from the formula, unless you add a space in between.

Comment: Sorry about that. I did not kew that someone will do it like the way you did that's why I did not included it in the question.